# Reverse function has only one argument but recursive function is passing 2 parameters

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
void reverse(int i);
int main()
{
    reverse(1);
}
void reverse(int i)
{
    if (i > 5)
        return ;
    printf("%d ", i);
    return reverse((i++, i));
}
```

please help me understand this code
output of this code is 12345

Comment: the `reverse()` is a `void` function, so it cannot return anything.  Your compiler should have told you about this problem.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note other compilers use different options to accomplish the same results